# Запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: пунктуация, сказуемые, приложение, подлежащее

> Один из наперсников Пугачёва,(1) тщедушный и сгорбленный старичок с седою бородою,(2) не имел ничего замечательного,(3) кроме голубой ленты,(4) надетой через плечо по серому армяку.

Запятые 1, 3, 4 обособляют дополнения. 
Почему стоит запятая номер 2? Подлежащее — "старичок", "не имел ничего замечательного" — сказуемое. Зачем запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым? Или, может быть, я неправильно определила главные члены предложения?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 и 2 - это запятые, обособляющие распространённое **приложение** "тщедушный и сгорбленный старичок с седою бородою".

Если [распространённое] приложение относится к нарицательному существительному, то оно обособляется в любом случае, вне зависимости от места в предложении. Например:

***Мой отец, капитан пограничных войск, служил на Дальнем Востоке. - Капитан пограничных войск, мой отец служил на Дальнем Востоке.*** [Обособление приложений](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_176)

Подлежащее в Вашем предложении не "старичок", а выражение "один из наперсников Пугачёва".

Обособленное приложение "тщедушный и сгорбленный старичок с седою бородою" находится между подлежащим и сказуемым, после определяемого сочетания слов "один из наперсников Пугачёва".