# Сомнительные запятые в сложном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение

В одном распространенном "занимательном" журнале попалось такое предложение (речь — об антилопах [**куду**](https://yandex.ru/collections/user/alinaa127/antilopa-kudu/)).

**А во время брачного сезона самцы сражаются за самку,**(1) **и бывает,**(2) **что,**(3) **сцепившись спиральными рогами,**(4) **они уже не могут освободиться друг от друга,**(5) **и вскоре погибают.**

Запятые (2) и (4) у меня сомнений не вызывают, а вот остальные — под вопросом.
Крутила-вертела-переставляла, но так и не смогла решить — правильно ли расставлены запятые.
А какой вам видится пунктуация в этом предложении?

Comment: Римма, а не лучше перед цифрами в скобках пробелы поставить?

Comment: Я ориентировалась на оформление других вопросов. Вот, посмотрите: (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/452110/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be) и (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/447489/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%bc). Как же ж быть?

Comment: Ну раз главный модератор создал такой прецедент, пускай так и будет.)) Куда-то Sharon пропала. :((

Answer (score 4):

> А во время брачного сезона самцы сражаются за самку,(1) и бывает,(2)
>   что,(3) сцепившись спиральными рогами,(4) они уже не могут
>   освободиться друг от друга,(5) и вскоре погибают.

1. самцы сражаются
2. бывает
3. они не могут освободиться и погибают

---

Лишняя зпт под нумером 5, остальные где надо - разделяют основы или обрамляют довески в виде деепричастных оборотов.

***А во время брачного сезона самцы сражаются за самку, и бывает, что, сцепившись спиральными рогами, они уже не могут освободиться друг от друга и вскоре погибают.***

Вот так вот видится.

Comment: Согласен, так же подумал. :)

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Спасибо большое, Галина, — Вы развеяли мои сомнения, но не все. Хочу уточнить: не является ли **А во время брачного сезона** общим второстепенным членом? Ведь тогда запятая перед первым союзом "и" не нужна. http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=353

Comment: Римулик, што Вы церемонная такая съ мною... Не-а. Не общий второстепенный. Но по правилам у нас знаток Шаронушка-Скок-Поскок-Головушка.

Comment: Поддерживаю Галину, это не общий член предложения. "Бывает"  относится к другой ситуации, ведь они не всегда погибают, а в отдельных случаях, когда не могут расцепиться.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо. Очень приятно заручиться Вашей поддержкой.

Comment: @Людмила Но ведь сцепление рогами, "неосвобождение" и гибель самцов происходят только в брачный сезон. Хорошее предложение получается, понятное и без первой части: _**А во время брачного сезона** бывает, что, сцепившись спиральными рогами, они уже не могут освободиться друг от друга и вскоре погибают._  Просто так (в другое время) сцепление не происходит (его не бывает).

Comment: Нет, Римулик. У нас "и бывает" - самостоятельное предложение с прилепившимся придаточным, в которое вклеился деепричастный оборот.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова: я тоже не совсем понял, почему "а во время брачного сезона" не может быть общей частью (и почему "и бывает" самостоятельное предложение).